# When $2$ $6$-sided die are rolled, what is the probability that the first is odd and the difference is $0$?

Tags: probability

The probability the the first die is odd is $\frac{3}{6}=\frac{1}{2}$.

The probability that first is odd and diff is $0$ is $\frac{3}{6}\cdot \frac{1}{6} = \frac{3}{36} = \frac{1}{12}$.

Is $\frac{1}{12}$ correct?

Comment: $\frac{3}{36}\neq \frac{1}{3}$.  Recognize that $\frac{3}{36}=\frac{3}{3\times 12}$ and so by cancelling a $3$ from both top and bottom, that leaves you with...

Comment: Apart from that, the answer of $\frac{3}{36}$ is correct.

Comment: Thanks, don't know why I put 1/3.

Comment: Another quick question:

Comment: Say A = first die is odd. B = diff is 0. To prove that they're independent, P(A∩B) = P(A) P(B). We know P(A) = 1/2 and P(B) = 1/6. So, P(A)P(B) = 1/12. And P(A∩B) = 1/12. So, since P(A∩B) = 1/12 = P(A)P(B), they're independent.

Comment: But aren't A and B actually dependent? So, how do they end up being equal?

Comment: What makes you say that $A$ and $B$ are dependent? It's true that $A$ and $A\cap B$ are dependent, but as you've shown, $A$ and $B$ are independent.

Comment: $A$ and $B$ are in fact *independent* in this example.  Ignore any "intuitive" definitions about independence and use the mathematical definition of independence.  As an aside, if you were intending to check for independence here using your calculations above, you should *not* have intended to write $P(A\cap B)=P(A)\times P(B)=\frac{3}{6}\times\frac{1}{6}$, but rather you should have meant it as $P(A\cap B)=P(A)\times P(B\mid A)=\frac{3}{6}\times\frac{1}{6}$.  Remember that $P(A\cap B)$ is equal to $P(A)\times P(B)$ if **and only if** $A$ and $B$ are independent.  If unknown then cannot use.

Comment: Through the proof, yes they're independent. But logically, doesn't the 2nd outcome depend on the first outcome? Like in order for the diff to be 0, the 2nd die MUST be whatever odd # was in the first die.

Comment: Although the *desired result* will depend on the first outcome, *the probability of achieving the desired result* does not.

Comment: Ah! I see the confusion. The probability that the second die matches the first is $1/6,$ regardless of whether the first die is even or odd. Thus, they are independent. The probability that the second die matches the first *and is even* will depend entirely on whether the first roll is even, so $A$ and $A\cap B$ are dependent.

Comment: By the way, you're being alerted to the comments because they are on your question, and JMoravitz was alerted because he was the only other commenter when you commented, so the system defaults to assuming that it is directed at him. However, in general, to direct a comment to someone specific, you need to use the "@," as in, @beepboopbeepboop. Welcome to Math.SE!

Comment: Oh, right! In particular, neither of us will be alerted to any future comments on this thread unless we are "tagged" in the comment.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thanks for your response. When checking for independence, why do most problems I come upon use P(A∩B)=P(A)×P(B) instead of P(A∩B)=P(A)×P(B∣A). We don't know if A and B are independent, and we're checking if they're independent, so why not always use the second formula.

Comment: @CameronBuie Thanks! I didn't know about this, clearly. Appreciate the welcome :)

Comment: We always know that $P(A\cap B)=P(A)\times P(B\mid A)$.  This we get for free.  If we wish to calculate $P(A\cap B)$, we may use the above, or we may do it with more direct methods.  We want to show whether this is equal to $P(A)\times P(B)$ or not to prove independence.  If it is equal, then they are independent.  If it is not equal then they are dependent and vice versa. We cannot assume that $P(A\cap B)=P(A)\times P(B)$ without assuming independence, so if you were to assume $P(A\cap B)=P(A)\times P(B)$ in order to prove independence or itself, then you have circular incorrect reasoning.

Answer (score 1):

Set $X_1$: outcome of the first die. There are three successful outcomes: $X_1 = 1, X_1 = 3, X_1 = 5$; since the probabilities are uniform, $P(X_1= \{1,3,5\}) = \frac{1}{6}$. 'Difference equal to $0$' means the second outcome is the same; hence, we need

$P(X_2 \cap X_1) = P(X_2 = 1|X_1=1)P(X_1=1) + P(X_2 = 3|X_1=3)P(X_1=3) + P(X_2 = 5|X_1=5)P(X_1=5) = \frac{1}{6} \times \frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{6} \times \frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{6} \times \frac{1}{6} = \frac{3}{36}$